Change linux kernel release string
I hope to somehow change the release string, i.e. the string which uname -r prints, and more importantly for me, which is used to construct the path for module lookup, without actually compiling / recompiling the kernel. Is this possible?
Background: my distribution (based on Ubuntu) likes to ship kernel package updates (and associated module package updates) without changing the release string, so the new versions of the packages overwrite the /boot/vmlinuz-$RELEASE file, and also the entire module tree in /lib/modules/$RELEASE. As a result, if the new kernel is broken somehow, I have no way to revert unless I step over the packaged versions. If I could force the kernel to think of itself as $RELEASE-backup, I could copy /boot/vmlinuz-$RELEASE to /boot/vmlinuz-$RELEASE-backup and /lib/modules/$RELEASE to /lib/modules/$RELEASE-backup before an update; then reverting would be just a matter of telling the bootloader about the backed up versions.

Since the response is so overwhelming :-) , here's one crazy idea: the uname structure is just about the only kernel bit that can be changed under the administrator control, and there is a field in it that is in general quite useless -- at least for my purposes: namely, the NIS domainname. So, in a "backup" initramfs script, set it to something distinct; rename the module tree accordingly; and wrap modprobe in a trivial script that changes the module path (using the -S option) if probing the uname info reveals it's running a backup kernel. Shocked? ;-) It should work, no?
